# why pass parameters of append like this self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank).I dont understand this,what is the purpose of this method

Tags: python

```
class Card:
    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"{self.rank['rank']} of {self.suit}"

class Deck:

    def __init__(self):
        
        self.cards=[]
        suits=['spades','clubs','hearts','diamonds']
        ranks=[
            {"rank": "A","value":11},
            {"rank":"2","value":2},
            {"rank":"3","value":3},
            {"rank":"4","value":4},
            {"rank":"5","value":5},
            {"rank":"6","value":6},
            {"rank":"7","value":7},
            {"rank":"8","value":8},
            {"rank":"9","value":9},
            {"rank":"10","value":10},
            {"rank":"J","value":10},
            {"rank":"Q","value":10},
            {"rank":"K","value":10}
        
            ]

        for suit in suits:
            for rank in ranks:
                self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank))
```

can write this code as another method

Comment: It creates a `Card` object then appends it to the list.

Comment: this is creating card object for all deck cards

Comment: How would you prefer to append items to a list?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

The nested for loops are building up the `self.cards` list. This can also be done with a list comprehension. The translation is fairly direct.

```
class Deck:
    def __init__(self):
        suits = ['spades', 'clubs', 'hearts', 'diamonds']
        ranks = [
            {"rank": "A", "value":11},
            {"rank":"2", "value":2},
            {"rank":"3", "value":3},
            {"rank":"4", "value":4},
            {"rank":"5", "value":5},
            {"rank":"6", "value":6},
            {"rank":"7", "value":7},
            {"rank":"8", "value":8},
            {"rank":"9", "value":9},
            {"rank":"10", "value":10},
            {"rank":"J", "value":10},
            {"rank":"Q", "value":10},
            {"rank":"K", "value":10}
        ]

        self.cards = [
            Card(suit, rank)
            for suit in suits
            for rank in ranks
        ]
```

Newlines for demonstration purposes. Could also be written as:

```
self.cards = [Card(suit, rank) for suit in suits for rank in ranks]
```

Comment: it means 'self.cards.append(Card(suit,rank))' from this automatically create object of card class??

Comment: `self.cards` has been assigned an empty list in your code. The loops add the different card info combinations to that list. The code I've shown does the exact same thing, but more directly.